# gunicorn not picking up changes in django code even after restarting

Tags: django, nginx, google-compute-engine, gunicorn

I have this web application that I built with django, and deployed with gunicorn and nginx on GCP Compute Engine Instance. I serve the static files with nginx.

For nginx, whenever I push new code to the server, run collectstatic, and restart nginx, I see the static file update working fine.

The problem begins with the server code. Whenever I push code to my django views, or run migrations, or push code to my html file, and restart gunicorn, I don't see the changes right away. It takes about a full day for the change to take effect. I have tried reloading daemon, restarting gunicorn, restarting nginx but the issue persists

For the nginx, here is my location settings on nginx configuration

```
location /static/ {
   alias /home/user/app/backend/static/;
}

location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

There you can see that I serve the static file using nginx, then pass every other request to the app.

Then when I push code to my github, pull it into the app, and run

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

Then restart nginx with

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Everything works great.

Now for the part that I think the problem comes from.
If I make a change to my index.html file (as you can see from the conf above, it is being served by the gunicorn), then restart both daemon and gunicorn

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart gunicorn.socket gunicorn.service
```

I do not see the changes in my app, even after clearning the cache in my browser. The thing is, I can see the change in my app when I open the scripts but even though, I don't see the change in my app on the web. And yes, I have `DEBUG=False` in my settings.py. However, after about a day or so, I start to see the changes.
It is almost as though there is a cache somewhere that is persistent for about a day or so.

Please any help at all will be appreciated.

Note: It is possible that the 1-day updating I noticed is entirely a coincidence and has nothing to do with the problem. I may have done the right thing within this timeframe but not know what it was. Also feel free to let me know if I am doing the hosting wrong completely. This is my first time

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Make sure that you are restarting both **Gunicorn** and **Nginx**. If you only restart **Gunicorn**, **Nginx** will continue to serve the old version of your app.

Comment: I am restarting both of them

Comment: Did you added any caching related code in nginx conf?

Comment: No I did not. I only added server, location and ssl code in the conf

Comment: The problem is definitely from my gunicorn because I have changed the name of my project completely but the website still works (backend is loading). However, the static files (served by nginx no longer works which is what I expect). The issue has to be from gunicorn. There is a cache somewhere that still runs

Comment: Hi Ankit, I have solved the issue. I had to stop gunicorn completely and start it again manually. I have posted my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved my issue.

I had to stop gunicorn completely using

```
pkill gunicorn
```

and restart it again using

```
gunicorn -c conf/gunicorn_config.py myproject.wsgi
```

I still don't know why I can't restart gunicorn using the normal command above but this works for me.